# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected EOF in prolog at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]

Tags: java, soap, cxf, webservice-client, webservices-client

I am trying to invoke soap webservice over https protocal.

I have wsdl and generated classes by using Apache CXF, version : 3.0.5

when i post the request in soapui, i am getting successfull response from server

but when the same is invoked from Java client getting error : `javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected EOF in prolog`

Below is java code

```
package com.cts.pepsi.util;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;

import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.oracle.xmlns.apps.financials.commonmodules.shared.model.erpintegrationservice.DocumentDetails;
import com.oracle.xmlns.apps.financials.commonmodules.shared.model.erpintegrationservice.ErpIntegrationService;
import com.oracle.xmlns.apps.financials.commonmodules.shared.model.erpintegrationservice.ErpIntegrationService_Service;
import com.oracle.xmlns.apps.financials.commonmodules.shared.model.erpintegrationservice.EssJob;
import com.oracle.xmlns.apps.financials.commonmodules.shared.model.erpintegrationservice.ObjectFactory;



public class SoapClient {
    private static final Logger           log      = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SoapClient.class);

    private String username = "username";
    private String password = "password";

    static ErpIntegrationService erpIntegrationService;
    static long value = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("START : Invoking  service");
        System.out.println("done");

        try {

            String documentAccount = null;
            String documentTitle = null;
            String fileName = null;
            String interfaceDetails = null;
            String jobName = null;
            String jobParams = null;
            EssJob essJob = new EssJob();
            List<EssJob> jobList = new ArrayList<EssJob>();
            ObjectFactory erpobjfac = new ObjectFactory();

                documentAccount = "abc$/xyz$/take$";
                documentTitle = "ekat throw bill";
                fileName = "abcd.zip";

                interfaceDetails = "2";

                jobName = "/pqr/stu/ddd/fdg/qwe/tyu/poi,lkj";
                jobParams = "090900909090909090909,andis,2016/05/17,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Y,null";

                essJob.setJobName(erpobjfac.createEssJobJobName(jobName));
                essJob.setParameterList(erpobjfac.createEssJobParameterList(jobParams));
                jobList.add(essJob);


            System.out.println("iiiii  ");
            StringBuffer encodedContent = new StringBuffer();
            encodedContent.append("encoded content");//here Base64 encoded data is appended

            //DocumentDetails
            DocumentDetails docDtls = new DocumentDetails();
            docDtls.setDocumentAccount(erpobjfac.createDocumentDetailsDocumentAccount(documentAccount));
            docDtls.setContentType(erpobjfac.createDocumentDetailsContentType("zip"));
            docDtls.setDocumentTitle(erpobjfac.createDocumentDetailsDocumentTitle(documentTitle));
            docDtls.setFileName(fileName);
            docDtls.setDocumentSecurityGroup(erpobjfac.createDocumentDetailsDocumentSecurityGroup("FAFtakeExcellent"));
            docDtls.setContent(encodedContent.toString().getBytes());


            //NotificationCode
            String notificationCode = "50";

            //CallBackURL
            String callbackURL = "http://somecallbackserver.domain.com/mycallback";


            new SoapClient().authenticate();
            JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
            factory.setServiceClass(ErpIntegrationService.class);
            //factory.setAddress("https://eeln-test.fin.us2.oraclecloud.com:443/publicFinancialCommonErpIntegration/ErpIntegrationService");
            factory.setAddress("http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/loadAndImportData");
            factory.getInInterceptors().add(new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor());
            factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor());
            //ErpIntegrationService erpIntServiceSoap = (ErpIntegrationService) factory.create();
            erpIntegrationService = (ErpIntegrationService) factory.create();


            value = erpIntegrationService.loadAndImportData(docDtls, jobList, interfaceDetails, notificationCode, callbackURL);
            System.out.println("value is not :- "+value);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("An exception occurred, exiting", e);
        }
    }

    public <K> void authenticate() {
          log.info("Entering authenticate ");
          try {
           ErpIntegrationService_Service erpIntgService_Service = new ErpIntegrationService_Service();

           this.erpIntegrationService = erpIntgService_Service.getErpIntegrationServiceSoapHttpPort();
           Map requestCredentails = ((BindingProvider) this.erpIntegrationService).getRequestContext();
           requestCredentails.put("javax.xml.ws.security.auth.username", this.username);
           requestCredentails.put("javax.xml.ws.security.auth.password", this.password);
           log.info("Exiting authenticate ");
          } catch (Exception exception) {
           log.info("Error in authenticate " + exception.getMessage());
          }
         }

}
```

## below is the log

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.loadAndImportData(Unknown Source)
    at com.cts.pepsi.util.SoapClient.main(SoapClient.java:109)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:685)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2141)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2047)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1131)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1154)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:165)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:802)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1645)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1533)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1336)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:652)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:138)
    ... 2 more
```

i have taken the soap request from the logs and posted from SOAP ui, it worked fine.

***i have tried to invoke all operations which exists in wsdl from Java client and the same error is repeated***

below is wsdl policy

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="ErpIntegrationServiceSoapHttpPort_Input_Policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
   <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
         <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <sp:Body/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"/>
            <sp:Header Name="fmw-context" Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/fmw/context/1.0"/>
         </sp:SignedParts>
         <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <sp:Body/>
            <sp:Header Name="fmw-context" Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/fmw/context/1.0"/>
         </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
      <wsp:All>
         <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <sp:Body/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"/>
            <sp:Header Name="fmw-context" Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/fmw/context/1.0"/>
         </sp:SignedParts>
         <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <sp:Body/>
            <sp:Header Name="fmw-context" Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/fmw/context/1.0"/>
         </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
      <wsp:All>
         <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <sp:Body/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"/>
            <sp:Header Name="fmw-context" Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/fmw/context/1.0"/>
         </sp:SignedParts>
         <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <sp:Body/>
            <sp:Header Name="fmw-context" Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/fmw/context/1.0"/>
         </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
      <wsp:All>
         <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <sp:Body/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"/>
            <sp:Header Name="fmw-context" Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/fmw/context/1.0"/>
         </sp:SignedParts>
         <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <sp:Body/>
            <sp:Header Name="fmw-context" Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/fmw/context/1.0"/>
         </sp:EncryptedParts>
      </wsp:All>
   </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

requesting you to please help where i have committed the mistake in java code, thanks

Comment: see this link, I think this will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432726/soap-header-unexpected-eof-in-prolog

Comment: Ramzan Shah http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432726/soap-header-unexpected-eof-in-prolog where exactly i should place in my code. please help me out